# Hamster.vector troubles with converting to json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm working with `Hamster` gem in my project and I faced with problem when serializing to json.
Here is what I'm toking about:

```
 hamster = Hamster.vector()
 => [] #is empty
 hamster.to_json
 => "{\"levels\":0,\"root\":[],\"size\":0}" # what is this?
```

So, my question is:

Can someone explain me why `Hamster` adding `levels`, `root` and `size` keys to the object and how can I remove them from my json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hamster = Hamster.vector()
 => [] #is empty
```

`Hamster.vector()` returns a singleton instance(`EmptyVector`) of `Hamster::Vector` class.

`[]` is displayed as an output because **[Enumerable#reduce](https://github.com/hamstergem/hamster/blob/master/lib/hamster/enumerable.rb)** is overridden by Hamster.

`levels`, `root` and `size` are instance variables of Class `Hamster::Vector` which are initialized in **[Hamster::Vector#initialize](https://github.com/hamstergem/hamster/blob/master/lib/hamster/vector.rb)** method.

So when you `hamster.to_json` you see the output as

```
 => "{\"levels\":0,\"root\":[],\"size\":0}"
```

Use `Hamster::Vector#empty?` method to check if your `hamster` object is empty? i.e., @size == 0

```
hamster.to_json unless hamster.empty?
```

This way if hamster is an empty object you don't convert it to json.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be `hamster.to_a.to_json`.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of Hamster has a .to_ruby function that comes in handy.

```
Hamster::Vector[].to_json          # => "\"#<Hamster::Vector:0x0000000238b678>\""
Hamster.to_ruby(Hamster::Vector[]) # => []
Hamster.to_ruby(Hamster::Vector[]).to_json # => "[]"
```

You can read more about Hamster.to_ruby [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/hamstergem/hamster/Hamster#to_ruby-class_method).

The good thing is that it works on every type defined by Hamster.
It also just returns 'nil' if the passed argument is 'nil'.